# File upload to custom folder in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

Hi I need to upload file in `react` using `class` `component` as it is legacy application. I need this file in `UI` only so I dont want to save it into database. I have to save in the `public folder` also under public folder I need to give fucntionality to user to give file and folder name.

What changes I need to do in below code. Below code is perfectly working. Only thing is I need to upload file to folder and need to manaully enter `file and folder name`.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class FileUpload extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedFile: null,
  };

  onFileChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  onFileUpload = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      'myFile',
      this.state.selectedFile,
      this.state.selectedFile.name
    );

    console.log(this.state.selectedFile);
    axios.post('api/uploadfile', formData);  //I need to change this line
  };

  fileData = () => {
    if (this.state.selectedFile) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>File Details:</h2>
          <p>File Name: {this.state.selectedFile.name}</p>
          <p>File Type: {this.state.selectedFile.type}</p>
          <p>
            Last Modified:{' '}
            {this.state.selectedFile.lastModifiedDate.toDateString()}
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <br />
          <h4>Choose before Pressing the Upload button</h4>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Plese select the translation file</h1>
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
          <button onClick={this.onFileUpload}>Upload!</button>
        </div>
        {this.fileData()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FileUpload;
```

Edit 1:-

[image]

Edit 2:-

```
app.listen(80, () => console.log('Listening on port 80'));
 axios.post('http://localhost:80/api/uploadfile', formData, {
```

Error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save file to the `public` folder it will not available to the front end until you build the react project (`react-scripts build`). Instead of that, you can be save it directly to `build` folder. But next time you build the project uploaded files are gone. You can decide what to do there.

Going back to your question,

You can achieve it using running a simple server which servers fronted build files and that handles some HTTP requests.

1. Install `express` (server) and `multer`(to handle file uplaod).

```
npm i express multer
```

2. In the root level of your react project create another folder called `server`. Within that create a file called `index.js` and add following code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const multer  = require('multer')

// setup multer for file upload
var storage = multer.diskStorage(
    {
        destination: './build',
        filename: function (req, file, cb ) {
            cb( null, file.originalname);
        }
    }
);

const upload = multer({ storage: storage } )

app.use(express.json());
// serving front end build files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));

// route for file upload
app.post("/api/uploadfile", upload.single('myFile'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file.originalname + " file successfully uploaded !!");
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port 3000"));
```

3. To start the above server change the `start` command in `scripts` sections in `package.json` file. It will build the project and start running the server.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node ./server",
    ...
    ...
}
```

4. Your file upload handler need to have content type as `multipart/form-data`

```
  onFileUpload = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("myFile", this.state.selectedFile);

    console.log(this.state.selectedFile);
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/uploadfile", formData, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    }); //I need to change this line
  };
```

Now run `npm start` and try uploading a file. It will appear in `build` folder. You might change it as per your needs.

Comment: @Niharika S, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you Amila. I am going through the same.

Comment: @Niharika S, Great !! can you please mark this as the answer if it really solved your issue? thanks!

Comment: Ofcourse I will mark. actually I already have start script in package.json for react. can I modify the same for the entry you suggested.  "start": "dotenv -e .env -- webpack-dev-server --hot --define process.env.dev --inline --port 80 --host localhost",

Comment: Yes, you need to change it, with webpack dev server you cannot start a server with express. You might need to change the port `80` in the code, I used `3000`

Comment: actually its not working..after selecting file when I am clicking in upload button nothing happening.

Comment: check the build folder file should be there if it's working fine. Otherwise, what's the error you get.

Comment: I put the error screenshot in question

Comment: did you change the port to `80` in the `server/index.js`? then change the request to `axios.post("http://localhost:80/api/uploadfile"`

Comment: ya...I changed in API call but it is giving 404 error.

Comment: I'm curious why it's not working. I guess you need to exit `yarn start` and rerun. hot relaoding does not work with the current command

Comment: I am doing yarn start

Comment: Hi Amila,my react applicatinon is alkready in port 80 so I think some issue is coming. is it possible instead of writing this index.js for server side, can we write something in react component to save files in folder? is it possible?

Comment: That is not possible, file saving should be done in the server side. I will send a git repo you can clone it and run. It's working for me.

Comment: sure Amila..that would be very helpful.

Comment: Here is the repo => https://github.com/Amila-Rukshan/react-file-uplaod, Do `yarn install`  and `yarn start`. App is in `localhost:80`

Comment: Thank you Amila...I copy pasted your code...still it is giving error... I posted in another questiuon

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593498/upload-file-in-react-app-at-ui-side-in-folder/70593715#70593715

Comment: can it be like server is not running for that API? because my react application is in port 80. is there any alternate for it.

Comment: You need to change the start script as I have given otherwise it won’t start the express server. That’s the issue.

Comment: but in that case my react applicion will not work...anything I can to modify dotenv commnad so that both works

Comment: It's just starting web-pack-dev server. Nothing much. Your react app also work with this line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));`. Have you tried to start it as given?

Comment: can you share the code in a repo to see what's going on.