# React Image upload with Axios - POST "URL" 404 (Not Found) - problem

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios

Unfortunately I am not able to upload an image to React using Axios.
I have here a normal form consisting of several input fields.
One of them is an input field of type "file" and I want to upload an image to it.
Through my research I quickly realized that many have this problem.
All solutions I tried so far do not work.
It is about my local development environment, for testing I installed it on my WebSpace, without success, same problem. (of course without the localhost baseUrL).
This is my last attempt.
Tried it also without async / await; as well as a direct inclusion of axios.

The error is always the same: `POST http://localhost:3000/images 404 (Not Found)`

for any help I would be very grateful!

Thank you very much for looking over it!

Here is my code:

my AddformData- Component:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
//import axios from 'axios'
import api from "./Api";

const AddformData = ({ onAdd }) => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [info, setInfo] = useState('');
    const [link, setLink] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    //Datum?

    /*const submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
         const formData = new FormData();
        //formData.append("name", name);  
        formData.append("file", image);
      
        axios     
          .post('/images', formData)   
          .then((res) => {  
            console.log(res);
            //alert("File Upload success");   
          })    
          .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err));   
      }; */

        const onSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            //if(!title ){ alert('Title missing'); }
            
            onAdd( {title, info, link, text, image} );
            
            setTitle('');
            setInfo('');
            setLink('');
            setText('');
            setImage('');

            const formData = new FormData();
            //formData.append("name", name);  
            formData.append("file", image);
          
            await api     
              .post('/images', formData)   
              .then((res) => {  
                console.log(res);
                //alert("File Upload success");   
              })    
              .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err));


        }

    return (
        <form className='add-form' onSubmit={ onSubmit }>
            // just the fields where it is all about for now: 

            {/* older relict from trying making a own uploader-component
             <FileUploader
                onFileSelectSuccess={(file) => setImage(file)}
                onFileSelectError={({ error }) => alert(error)}
            />
            */ }

            <div className='form-control'>
                <label>Add image</label>
                <input 
                    type='file'                    
                    acept='image/*'
                    onChange={(e) => setImage( [...e.target.files] )}
                    />
            </div>
            <input style={{background: 'green'}} className='btn' type='submit' value='Speichern' />

        </form>
    )
}

export default AddformData
```

here is my Api-component:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
 baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000/",
});

export default api
```

Comment: Have you try to make a request with `Postman` or other client request? it's `404` which mean there are no content in that link, and if you are running your react on port `3000`, you are firing a request to your own frontend.

Comment: I've read that before, right - in all resources it is shown like that or similar; so have I completely misunderstood the use of axios here? I want to upload the image into my designated folder and save, that's actually quite all

Comment: `designated folder` in your react application? Well it is not possible refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588644/file-upload-to-custom-folder-in-react, what you can do is build a simple server that handle file upload and serve image. Say for example the server open on port `8000` on your local. your axios will request to `axios.post('http://localhost:8000/path/to/upload/files')`

Comment: Well if you want the easy way without running a nodejs app. You can use this, https://api.imgbb.com/ . But I don't know the limitation of each apikey, I just test it once, and it works fine. Don't forget to add the file as `image` key, and the API Key as `key`

Comment: I see, it's very unfamiliar as a former PHP developer; whereas nothing happens by itself and quite magically in PHP either; I'll try that in any case! Thank you for your time! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: hate to say it, i checked the stackoverflow-link you posted, followed the whole process and still get the same 404 error ... there seems something not correct in the step by step guide ... ? outdated?

Comment: in step 3 there is this:  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node ./server",
    ...
    ...
}

but this starts making a prod build ... ? i add just && node ./server to the existing npm start commandn in that package json file

Comment: Normally I change the `"start": "node app.js", "dev": "nodemon app.ja"`, and i have tested the code. It works fine.

Comment: small update,sry for wasting your time, but maybe it will interest you or others: 
- found and solved stupid mistake in my DIR 
- next was 500 error; the problem seems to be that in package JSON the "start" comand: "react-scripts start && node ./server" seems to not work.
If I enter the commands separately in the terminal, the server also runs, which leads to next error: 
- no 404 anymore, but the connection with specified port is rejected. 
This is my status at the moment. I have installed my project as a repo from Mac to Windows as well, but I have the same problems there.